# Expectation of a random variable and an indicator function

Tags: probability-theory, expectation

Suppose you have a random variable $X$, and an event $A$. How do you evaluate the expectation $\mathbb E[X\ \mathbb{I}_{A}]$?

Comment: An alternative to the par answer is to  use the law of total expectation: $$ E[X 1_{\{A\}}] = \underbrace{E[X1_{\{A\}}|A]}_{E[X|A]}P[A] + \underbrace{E[X1_{\{A\}}|A^c]}_{0}(1-P[A])$$ and so $E[X1_{\{A\}}]=E[X|A]P[A]$, useful when the conditional expectation can be computed easily.  This assumes $P[A]>0$.  If $P[A]=0$ then $X1_{\{A\}}=0$ with prob 1, so its expectation is also $0$.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you mean by "evaluate." By definition,
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[X\mathbb{I}_{A}\right]=\int_{A}X(\omega)\mathbb{I}_{A}(\omega)d\mathbb{P}(\omega)=\int_{A}X(\omega)d\mathbb{P}(\omega),
$$
so to evaluate the expression, you would compute the integral above.
Practically speaking, if you are performing a Monte Carlo simulation,
the algorithm is as follows:

```
accumulator = 0
for n in [1, ..., N]:
    generate a sample omega from your distribution
    if omega is in A:
        accumulator += X(omega)
    endif
endfor
expectation = accumulator / N
```

Comment: What is `y` in your pseudo-code?

Comment: Should have been ```accumulator```; fixed.