# show that Conditional Expectation inequality exists

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

Let $X$ be a random variable with $E[X] < ∞$. Let A be an event with P(A) > 1- $\delta$. How can I show that this inequality with the conditional expectation of X given A exists:

$E[X|A] \geq E[X] - P(A^{c})$

Comment: The unique additional assumption that can save this inequality is $X\leq 1-\delta$ a.s.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I don't think so that I have to have an assumption like that. I think it must be something with the Conditional expectation with respect to an event [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_an_event)

Comment: See example of zoli. This inequality fails without some additional requirements. There are no ways to prove wrong inequality.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. In case I set the assumption provided, how can I prove the inequality? How can I expand the conditional expectation? Thanks

Comment: $\mathbb E[X|A]=\frac{\mathbb E[X\mathbf 1(A)]}{\mathbb P(A)} = \frac{\mathbb E[X]}{\mathbb P(A)}-\frac{\mathbb E[X\mathbf 1(A^c)]}{\mathbb P(A)}\geq \mathbb E[X] -\frac{\mathbb E[X\mathbf 1(A^c)]}{1-\delta}$. If $X\leq 1-\delta$ a.s., use it in the last term to get $\mathbb E[X|A]\geq \mathbb E[X] -\frac{(1-\delta)\mathbb E[\mathbf 1(A^c)]}{1-\delta}=\mathbb E[X] -\mathbb P(A^c)$.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. As I am quite new withe probability and these topics, can you please give me some more information how I expand the $[X1(A)]/ℙ(A)$?

Comment: There is no way to expand it further without any information on distribution of $X$ and on event $A$.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  What about this derivation (how these two are equal?): $\frac{E[X1(A)]}{P(A)} = \frac{E[X]}{P(A)} - \frac{E[X1(A^c)]}{P(A)}$? $E[X1(A)]$ is equal with?

Comment: Try to apply at least a little of your own efforts.

Comment: I am not sure whether I got it right that's why I asked you. I want to ensure that I got it correct. But anyway thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X=1$ or $-1$ with the same probability. $$E [X]=0, \ \ E [X\mid X=1]=1,\ \ E [X\mid X=-1]=-1.$$ Let $A=\{X=-1\}$ and $\delta=\frac23.$

Now,
how could the following inequality hold $$-1\geq0-\frac12?$$

Comment: Thanks for your comment. $X$ is random variable and A is an event. It must be something with indicator functions. [Conditional expectation with respect to an event
](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_an_event)

Comment: What do you want to say by "$X$ is a random variable and $A$ is an event"? Is $A=\{X=-1\}$ not an event?

Comment: $A$ is an event. I think we might need to use an indicator function, with 1 and 0, whether the event will take place. We might need to use this expansion? [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1850136/expectation-of-a-random-variable-and-an-indicator-function)

Comment: I still don't understand. Did my example not show that the inequality dos not hold in general? I suspect that you missed some further conditions excluding counter examples like mine.